# jquery console gives an undefined output on $('#div').height

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery for my header to be unfixed at a certain point. It works great but, when i try to get the height of my header it gives an undefined result.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="header.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="header">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**Jquery**

```
$.fn.followTo = function (height) {
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function (e) {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > height) {
        $('#header').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: height
        });
    } else {
        $('#header').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0
        });
    }
});
};
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var headerHeight = $('#header').height();
console.log(windowHeight, headerHeight);

$('#header').followTo(windowHeight-headerHeight);
```

As you can probably see the header.js is external, but that should not give any problems.

Comment: are this code is in footer or bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said thhat this code is in external file and you added it in `<head>`.So

What happen is:-

your jQuery code registered before the document is Ready/Rendered completely. That's why it will not recognize any `HTML` element and won't work

When you put it on bottom, it will wait for document to be Ready/Rendered properly and then your jQuery code will register and will recognize all HTML elements and start working

I hope it will clear your doubt now.

***Solution:-***

Load your external jquery file on the bottom of the current file.

Answer (score 1):

@Jeoren: The reason most of the jQuery goes in the bottom of the page as you would need DOM to be ready for manipulation. You can even have external file in header, just make sure to write:

```js
$(function(){
//your code goes here
});
```

You also have to make sure that your external js added to page after jQuery library in order to get $ object. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you try to get a height for an element before the page is even laid out completely. So the browser is yet unable to determine a height (and returns null).

Try to put your code into a loading event handler:

```
$(document).load(function(){
// your code here
});
```

Comment: I tried $(document).load(function(){...}); but it gave “Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function”. So I also tried $(document).on('load', function(){...}); and it returned nothing.

Comment: @JeroenvanderWal i the jquery code is on bottom of page? or added somewhere in `<head>`

Comment: @Anant It's in a separate .js file and i imported it in the <head>.

Comment: Could you explain me why it needs to be at the bottom? It works now but i want to know why.